# enable HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in runtime

Tags: java, jconsole

according to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html it should be possible to enable -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError using JConsole in runtime. How?

I assume its somewhere under MBeans tab and the com.sun.management -> HotSpotDiagnostic -> Operations -> setVMOptions ?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you have to use the setVMOption with "`HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`" as p0 and "`true`" as p1 parameter according to the [Monitoring and Managing Java SE 6 Platform Applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/monitoring-141801.html).